# Mathematical algorithm to alter values to specific range

Tags: algorithms

[image: pic]

I have a scroll bar in a computer program that scrolls from is -1 to 1.Its initial value is 0 .I need it to scroll from 0 to 1 and the initial value to be 0.5  
What is the mathematical way to multiply the numbers by something in order to have the range 0 to 1 and the center to be 0.5

Can it be done in some type of function ? Any help will be appreciated

**Note** : *The red values are the range I want to reach in my scrolling bar*

Comment: yes , I fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the original value is $x$, add 1 and divide it by 2 ($\frac{x+1}{2}$) to get what you want.

The range will go from $\frac{-1 + 1}{2}=0$ to $\frac{1+1}{2} = 1$, and the inital value will be $\frac{0 + 1}{2} = 0.5$.